# fare well doing and work well doing

Tags: verbs

Is it OK to say fare well or work well doing something?

> You can't *fare well* teaching the students if you are not totally involved.

> You can *work well* persuading them into buying your products if you keep practicing.

Comment: _Fare well_ sounds odd because of the use of _farewell_ to mean _goodbye_, though we do say _fare badly_. I would prefer _succeed in/at_.

Answer (score 1):

I personally have used the phrase “fare well” before. For instance:

> The new feather toy we got for our kitten isn’t faring very well.

The phrase usually refers to living creatures, as it has a connotation of referring to wellbeing. On the other hand, “work well” is used for objects, like computers, and not for living beings.